# extern const type и namespace

Tags: c++

Что бы сделать const type с внешним связыванием:

```
//i.h
extern const type i;

//i.cpp
#include <i.h>
extern const type i = ...;

//main.cpp
#include <i.h>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << i;               
}
```

А как себя должно правильно вести это правило в namespace конструкциях? Будет ли исключение из правил и extern для const не понадобится в именованом namespace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Константы в C++ имеют внутреннее связывание. Так что это не зависит от того, в каком пространстве имен определена константа.

Другое дело не константные переменные. Если они определены в неименованном пространстве имен, или в пространстве имен, которое имеет внутреннее связывание, то они сами будут иметь внутреннее связывание.

Comment: В моей примере, разве extern не указывает что константная переменная объявлена с внешним связыванием?

Comment: @VladformMoscow вот похожий вопрос https://clck.ru/9beDU Я понимаю что по дефолту const переменные без extern объявляются с внутренним связыванием.

Comment: @relaxGalaxy Я вам ответил на вопрос. Что у вас вызывает сомнения? С какой целью вы приводите вашу ссылку? Что вы хотите сказать?

Comment: @VladformMoscow , я узнать хочу как работает это правило в неймспейсах, нужно ли константные переменные объявлять там с extern. Ссылку привел тк вы в нем отвечали на похожий вопрос, о том как объявить константную переменную с внешним связыванием.

Comment: @relaxGalaxy Так я вам на мой взгляд ответил вполне ясно. Еще раз, что вызывает сомнение?

Comment: "Константы в C++ имеют внутреннее связывание. Так что это не зависит от того, в каком пространстве имен определена константа." но ведь можно их сделать не с внутренним связыванием, а с внешним при помощи extern или вы имели введу что и в неймспейсах нужно указывать extern?

Comment: @relaxGalaxy Константы имеют внутреннее связывание независимо от того, в каком пространстве имен они определены. Если вы хотите, чтобы константа имела внешнее связывание, вы должны указать спецификатор extern. Так выглядит яснее?

Comment: @relaxGalaxy Вы же спрашиваете, как меняются правила в зависимости от используемого пространства имен, не так ли? Я вам отвечаю, что для констант правило не зависит от  того, в каком пространстве имен объявлена константа.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30827/discussion-between-vlad-from-moscow-and-relaxgalaxy).

Comment: @relaxGalaxy Я могу лишь повторить уже то, что вам написал.:)